# The restaurant is in an **inconvenient** location

Tags: word-usage

The restaurant is in an **inconvenient** location.

Does the sentence mean "the restaurant is not located nearby"?

Answer (score 5):

[Definition 1 from dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inconvenient) is pretty clear:

> **inconvenient**(adj): not easily accessible or at hand.

The restaurant could be far away or perhaps located in a busy area with no good parking or a bad part of town or any number of other factors that make it difficult to access.  An **inconvenient** location is one that has *any* factor that makes it difficult to access.